# Is iOS UILabel constraint from code with margin broken?

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to implement a popup layout like following:

[image: popup layout]

This works fine in a storyboard with margins and everything. In storyboard it looks like this:

[image: storyboard overview]

But if I make the same constraint in code I get this result:

[image: popup dialog]

The label has a light blue background and the view the label is inside has the dark blue background. The popup background has a border around itself. So basically the popup matches the child but the label inside the child overflows parent and grand parent BUT only because it has margins... If I remove margins it goes right to the border!

I've tryed making the exact same constraint just in code. I'm very open for alternative suggestions involving automatic adjusting width.

My code for creating popup:

```
func showPopup(caller: UIView) {
    closePopups()

    // setup view
    currentPopup = UIView()
    self.view.addSubview(currentPopup)
    currentPopup.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(Constants.Colors.white, alpha: 1)

    // setup constraints
    currentPopup.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // top constraint
    let topSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: currentPopup, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: intoWordsBar.view, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    self.view.addConstraint(topSideConstraint)

    // setup child elements
    var children = [PopupChildButton]()

    let childOne = createChild("writing_strategy_1", parent: currentPopup, aboveChild: nil, hasBorder: true, feature: FeatureManager.BarFeature.WriteReadLetterName)
    children.append(childOne)
    let childTwo = createChild("writing_strategy_2", parent: currentPopup, aboveChild: children[0], hasBorder: true, feature: FeatureManager.BarFeature.WriteReadLetterSound)
    children.append(childTwo)
    let childThree = createChild("writing_strategy_3", parent: currentPopup, aboveChild: children[1], hasBorder: true, feature: FeatureManager.BarFeature.WriteReadWord)
    children.append(childThree)
    let childFour = createChild("writing_strategy_4", parent: currentPopup, aboveChild: children[2], hasBorder: false, feature: FeatureManager.BarFeature.WriteReadSentence)
    children.append(childFour)

    let parentSize = getWidth(caller)

    //TODO MARK: <-- here working, need to add toggle function and graphics to childrens, documentation on methods, move to constructor class?

    // setup rest of constraints
    // add bottom constraint, equal to bottom of last child
    let bottomSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: currentPopup, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: children[children.count-1], attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    self.view.addConstraint(bottomSideConstraint)

    // left constraint
    let leftSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: currentPopup, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: caller, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: (-parentSize)/2)
    self.view.addConstraint(leftSideConstraint)

    // add border
    currentPopup.addBorder(edges: [.All], colour: UIColorFromHex(Constants.Colors.dark_grey, alpha: 1), thickness: 1)

    //TODO <-- last piece
    //childOne.addTarget(self, action: #selector(KeyboardViewController.childClick(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    //childTwo.addTarget(self, action: #selector(KeyboardViewController.childClick(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    //childThree.addTarget(self, action: #selector(KeyboardViewController.childClick(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    //childFour.addTarget(self, action: #selector(KeyboardViewController.childClick(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

My code for creating child:

```
func createChild(text: String, parent: UIView, aboveChild: UIView?, hasBorder: Bool, feature: FeatureManager.BarFeature) -> PopupChildButton {
    // setup child element
    let childBtn = PopupChildButton()
    childBtn.setRelatedFeature(feature)

    // set the right background color
    if intoWordsBar.getFeatureManager().isFeatureActive(feature) {
        childBtn.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(Constants.Colors.light_blue, alpha: 1)
        //childBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Checkmark"))
    } else {
        childBtn.backgroundColor = UIColorAndAlphaFromHex(Constants.Colors.transparent)//TODO Highlight implementation needs to be optimized, icon should be moved all the way to the left... somehow //TODO Add new checkmark icon
        //childBtn.setImage(nil)
    }

    childBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    parent.addSubview(childBtn)


    // add constraints
    // top constraint
    if let aboveChild = aboveChild {
        let topSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: childBtn, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: aboveChild, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        parent.addConstraint(topSideConstraint)
    } else {
        let topSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: childBtn, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: parent, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        parent.addConstraint(topSideConstraint)
    }

    // height constraint
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: childBtn, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: CGFloat(Constants.Sizes.popupChildHeight))
    parent.addConstraint(heightConstraint)

    // left constraint
    let leftSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: parent, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: childBtn, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    parent.addConstraint(leftSideConstraint)

    // right constraint
    let rightSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: parent, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: childBtn, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    parent.addConstraint(rightSideConstraint)

    // add border
    if hasBorder {
        childBtn.addBorder(edges: .Bottom, colour: UIColorFromHex(Constants.Colors.dark_grey, alpha: 1), thickness: 1)
    }

    // create grandchildren
    let label = UILabel()

    // setup looks
    label.textColor = UIColorFromHex(Constants.Colors.black, alpha: 1)
    label.textAlignment = .Center

    childBtn.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(Constants.Colors.dark_blue, alpha: 1)
    label.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(Constants.Colors.light_blue, alpha: 1)
    label.text = text.localized

    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    childBtn.addSubview(label)

    // add constraints
    // left constraint label
    let leftLabelConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: childBtn, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: CGFloat(Constants.Sizes.popupMargin))
    childBtn.addConstraint(leftLabelConstraint)

    // right constraint label
    let rightLabelConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: childBtn, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: CGFloat(Constants.Sizes.popupMargin))
    childBtn.addConstraint(rightLabelConstraint)

    // top constraint
    let labelTopSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: childBtn, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    childBtn.addConstraint(labelTopSideConstraint)

    // bottom constraint
    //let labelBottomSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: childBtn, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    //childBtn.addConstraint(labelBottomSideConstraint)


    return childBtn
}
```

Comment: Try to reverse the items in the `rightLabelConstraint` or make the constant a negative number: `-CGFloat(Constants.Sizes.popupMargin)`

Comment: @Laffen that worked =/ why? Why does that work?

Comment: To be honest; not sure. What's the result when replacing `.Right` with `.Trailing` ?

Comment: @Laffen they behave the same way. So my conclusion is that on iOS constraints define not only how one side relates to another but how they relate to each other. This is VERY different from my Android mindset with RelativeLayout where the parent sets some outer borders and the children can't affect their parents.

Comment: Every view can set its own size regardless of the parent view size, but the location of a subview should always be relative to the parent. Any constraints made for a subview, can't affect the size/location of the parent. The subviews just hangs onto the parent like a wart. Maybe some NSLayoutConstraint guru will catch this post and give a more fulfilling explanation. Have a good one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not broken.
When defining trailing constraints you must set the parent view as the first item and the child view as the second item. This is in reversed order compared to a leading constraint.

I pulled to constraints from a storyboard to illustrate this. These constraints make sure the header has a 10px margin from leading and trailing of parent view.

[image: TrailingConstraint]
[image: LeadingConstraint]

Comment: I've used left and right mostly, but I changed the one with trailing and leading with no success.

Comment: Okay so I changed the one with right to following and now everything works:         let rightLabelConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: childBtn, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: label, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: CGFloat(Constants.Sizes.popupMargin))
        childBtn.addConstraint(rightLabelConstraint)